# Using data.table and RJSONIO / jsonlite - results are transposed

Tags: r, data.table, rjsonio, jsonlite

I have implemented a wrapper library part of rstudio's htmlwidgets that renders a pivot table.
The package is [here](https://github.com/smartinsightsfromdata/rpivotTable).

The package works well with data.tables and data.frame (as it should!). For example it works with iris.
On the other hand if I try to convert iris to data.table my package (actually htmlwidgets - which internally uses RJSONIO) throws an error.

I know that it seems convoluted, but you can sort of reproduce the error just checking the difference between the following codes:

```
library(data.table)
library(RJSONIO)
data.table(fromJSON(toJSON(data.table(iris))))
```

The result is different from the dear iris dataset:

```
                                           V1
1:                   5.1,4.9,4.7,4.6,5.0,5.4,
2:                   3.5,3.0,3.2,3.1,3.6,3.9,
3:                   1.4,1.4,1.3,1.5,1.4,1.7,
4:                   0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.4,
5: setosa,setosa,setosa,setosa,setosa,setosa,
```

On the other hand jsonlite is able to re-build iris properly (just remember to detach RJSONIO before running the code):

```
    library(data.table)
    library(jsonlite)
    data.table(fromJSON(toJSON(data.table(iris))))

     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
```

I am not sure if the problems lies with data.table or RJSONIO...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to json.
`RJSONIO::fromJSON` returns `list` while `jsonlite::fromJSON` returns `data.frame`.
It is related to `data.table` call on `list` which is different than call on `data.frame`, but still behave as expected.
Try `as.data.table` instead of `data.table` in the outer call.

```
as.data.table(fromJSON(toJSON(data.table(iris))))
```

This was already discussed on data.table github. I've reply to your issue the reference to the discussion.

Comment: I've accepted your solution as it solve the question.  On the other hand I still have the bug in my package when I use a dot in the column name (e.g. data.table(iris) - or as.data.table(iris) ), probably due to a RJSONIO conversion.  See my comment on github.

Comment: The suggestion you posted on github is correct: data.table ```1.9.5``` fixes the problem with the dot!!